# How do I change the size and/or weight of emitted text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building a simple chat app for practice and want to style what is emitted. Specifically, I'd like the timestamp to be a smaller size (or maybe a different shade) and the user name to be bold.

I've tried `user.bold()`, but that emits `<b>user</b>`.

I've tried CSS in-line styling, `$("user").css({"font-style": "bold"})` and `$("#initials").css({"font-style": "bold"})`, but neither does anything.

And I've tried `getElementByID('user')`. Nada. (Don't ask what I wrote around that because I've been plugging away at this for hours and can't remember...)

When I adjust my CSS file, it only affects the input field and not the text that is emitted.

Here's my code (EDIT/NOTE: I've included a little more of my client-side .js file):

```js
   

$('form').submit(function () {
    var user = $('#initials').val();
    var text = $('#message').val();
    var dt = new Date();
    var ampm = (Date <12 || Date === 24) ? "AM" : "PM";
    var time = "(" + (dt.getHours() % 12 || 12) + ":" + ("0" + dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + dt.getSeconds()).slice(-2) + ampm + ") ";
    socket.emit('message', time + user + ': ' + text);
    $('#message').val('');
    return false;
});

socket.on('message', function (msg) {
  $('<li>').text(msg).appendTo('#history');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="initials" maxlength="2">
  <input id="message">
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

EDIT – Here's the relevant part of my CSS file:

```
body {
    background-color:white;
    color: #303030;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
input {
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#initials {
    width: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<main>
    <ol id="history">
    </ol>

    <form>
        <input id="initials" maxlength="2">
        <input id="message">
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>
</main>
```

Here's what I see:

[image]

Looking forward to seeing what solutions you might have! 90% of what I've built so far has come from this forum and community. XO

Comment: `$("user").css("font-style": "bold")` is wrong indeed. It should be `$("user").css({ "font-style": "bold" })`

Comment: Can you post your code where you're listening for messages on the socket, and append them to the DOM?

Comment: Wouldn't `$("user")` target a `HTML` tag of `<user>` And `getElementByID('user')` is incorrect, it would be `document.getElementById('user')` but this would also mean you are duplicating `ID`'s which is not recommended.

Comment: I think editing your CSS stylesheet is the simplest way to go about this. By in-lining (especially with javascript) you are complicating what should be a simple issue -- especially since you appear to have a working stylesheet. What do your html and CSS selectors look like? Particularly around your message display.

Comment: @JulioBetta I did include the curly brackets in my code. I mistyped in this post. My apologies. I've since fixed it.

Comment: @fubar I don't know what that means... But I've included a little more code from my client side. Do you mean the server side?

Comment: @shmootidy - that's exactly what I wanted to see. I've posted an answer.

Comment: @NewToJS 

You're totally right. I got mixed up and thought it targeted the variable that connects to `#initials`. I've been doing JS for all of 2 days :) 

And yes, I did write `document` – I totally forgot. Brain overload. I was trying to cobble together something using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) as a guide, but couldn't figure it out since that's about adjusting existing text, not styling text that is emitted by JS.

Comment: @Frish I don't think editing the CSS is going to work. Both the timestamp and the user name (`#initials`) are emitted from the JS. Any time I've messed with the CSS, it only affects the appearance of the text in the input fields. Once I submit, the styling doesn't apply.

Comment: @JesseJay Not sure what you mean. I've tried both `$("user").css` and `$("#initials").css` and neither make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change this line from using the `text` method, which escapes HTML entities, to `html`, it'll fix your issue.

```
$('<li>').html(msg).appendTo('#history');
```

You will then be able to include HTML in your messages:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var user = $('#initials').val();
    var text = $('#message').val();
    var dt = new Date();
    var ampm = (Date <12 || Date === 24) ? "AM" : "PM";
    var time = "(" + (dt.getHours() % 12 || 12) + ":" + ("0" + dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + dt.getSeconds()).slice(-2) + ampm + ") ";
    socket.emit('message', '<span class="timestamp">' + time + '</span> <span class="user">' + user + '</span>: <span class="message">' + text + '</span>');
    $('#message').val('');
    return false;
});

socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    $('<li>').html(msg).appendTo('#history');
});
```

And you can then write CSS to target these classes:

```
.timestamp {
    font-size: 10px;
}
.user {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.message {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: All right! That totally worked! Thank you!

Now, what about changing the font size of the time stamp? 

`"<font-size: 10px>" + time + "</font-size>"` doesn't work. Neither does `"<span style=font-size: 10px>" + time + "</span>"`.

Comment: `<font-size>` isn't a valid HTML tag. See my updated answer.

Comment: You rule! Thanks so much. 

That's so interesting that you can use CSS to target classes that you create in the JS file. It kind of blows my mind. I have so much to learn.

Comment: The CSS is still only styling the DOM. The only difference is you're using JavaScript to add new elements to the DOM.